# C# Little library with DataGrid control

Tags: c#, datagrid

I need to create a little library that has the DataGrid control as frontend.

In fact this library will have just 2 columns:
Filename;FileProperty

The filenames will be scanned again on each application start, the FileProperty column will be filled at runtime (if my application did an action the file) and should then be also be shown.
Futhermore i also need a filtering possiblity by the Filename column.
Sorting by both columns should also be possible.

There will be around 10.000 datarows in the library.
Persisiting / saveing data to the harddisk is not needed => everything should happen in RAM.

How to do this in easiest / best / fastest way?
Which structure (DataSet, DataTable, ..) gives best performance?

Comment: Yes, a DataSet is much faster than a DataTable.

Answer (score -1):

The DataGrid does not need a DataSet/Table.
In your case the best would be to create a DataGrid and set VirtualMode = true and handle the events from CellValueNeeded.  Then you can have alle the filenames in a SortedDictionary.
Use a FileSystemWatcher to update the grid with changes.

Comment: -1, programming against a Control always becomes a mess. You want some sort of backing store, preferably not a DataTable.